# find where activemq is running

Tags: activemq-classic

I am starting to study ActiveMQ, and there is one question that I must have the answer as soon as possible: is it possible for a, say, console program, to know the IP of the machine where ActiveMQ is running without any previous information, like configuration file, or a parameter passed to the program? I wonder if ActiveMQ answers to some type of broadcast network message, reporting the IP of the computer it is running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While your question is a bit vague on actual requirements and network capabilities etc, the most reasonable answer to this is to use discovery via multicast to locate a broker to connect to.  There is documentation for this [here](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-discovery-multicast-and-zeroconf.html), [here](http://activemq.apache.org/multicast-transport-reference.html), [here](http://activemq.apache.org/discovery.html) and some [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/Using_Networks_of_Brokers/files/FMQNetworksDiscoveryAgent.html) and more if you bother to search Google.

When you enable discovery on the broker's transport connector it will broadcast via multicast the IP address and port where a client can connect.  You should do some research and even browse the ActiveMQ code to see how this works.

Comment: I will check on the links you listed.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

No, that's not possible.  If all of the world's ActiveMQ servers were broadcasting their connection info to every producer or consumer in the world, that would be a ton of traffic.  And if they were, how's a producer of consumer supposed to know which one to connect to, without being told?  You have to tell the client how to reach the broker, and it's not a big deal to do.

Comment: True, but the software (executable, library, service, server) that would want to know where a ActiveMQ would be running, would limit its search to a specific network, like `234.199.093.*`. I can't imagine a programer writing a search in `*.*.*.*`. And if one did it, I doubt it would pass a basic test.

Thanks for your time!